# prevent contenteditable adding div on enter using pure javascript NOT jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, css

prevent contenteditable adding div on enter using pure javascript NOT jQuery

like this example http://jsfiddle.net/uff3M/

but I need it in javascript not jQuery

I solved my problem Thanks all

```js
function enterToBr(e){
    var evt = e || window.event;
    var keyCode = evt.charCode || evt.keyCode;
    if(keyCode==13){
            document.execCommand('insertHTML', false, '<br>');
            return false;
    }
}
```

```css
div{
    border:1px black solid;
    padding:10px;
}
```

```html
<div contenteditable="true" id="container" onkeydown="enterToBr()">
When Enter it's create new div inside container , but I need when user press enter key create new br not new div
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function enterToBr(e){
    var evt = e || window.event;
    var keyCode = evt.charCode || evt.keyCode;
    if(keyCode==13){
            document.execCommand('insertHTML', false, '<br>');
    }
}
```

```css
div{
    border:1px black solid;
    padding:10px;
display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div contenteditable="true" id="container" onkeydown="enterToBr()">
When Enter it's create new div inside container , but I need when user press enter key create new br not new div
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like all you still need to do, is properly prevent the event’s default action - `return false` alone does not do that in this situation.

You either need to pass this return value up the chain inside the HTML attribute used to add the handler function,

```
onkeydown="return enterToBr()"
```

or you prevent it using the appropriate method,

```
    if(keyCode==13){
            document.execCommand('insertHTML', false, '<br>');
            evt.preventDefault();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that will CSS too.

Add `display: inline-block;` to your div:

```
div{
    display: inline-block;
}
```